# trouble with Polhemus G4 system

Tags: sensors

High, I started work in a research group. I was asked to use the the Polhemus G4 system and a system by Eliko (provides position in the room) to identify at what target a user is looking at in a room. the Polhemus sensor will be attached to the user's head so that we can use its yaw, pitch and height readings (since we need to know where exactly is the user's head even when sitting...) .

Unfortunately, occasional and with no reason the G4 system starts to malfunction. The system starts giving incorrect readings. We do not have any idea why this happens (even when using a different copy of the system). Here is one result when I was looking straight forwards without moving my head (sensor taped to my head).
The image I included shows the room, I was in with the lines showing my gaze direction

As you can see in the image despite me barely moving the lines start rotating by themselves and getting lower.

We can't figure out why this happens, we tried restarting the system but we still get problems. The only thing that seems to work is leaving it for a few hours then it starts working again. Any ideas what is going on?

[the direction that the system thought I was looking at when collecting data based on polhemus reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZkeq.png)

note; we also tried moving it away from metals.